# SQL: How do you count the number of unique records?

Tags: sql, count, unique, teradata

I'm new to SQL and sorry if this q has been asked before - I couldn't phrase it properly.

Say I have a table that looks like this:

```
Name    Call ID
Sally   1
Sally   2
Sally   3
Mike    4
Mike    5
Bob     6
Bob     7
```

I want to create a new table that looks like this:

```
Name    No. of calls
Sally   3
Mike    2
Bob     2
```

**Attempt**

I assume I would do something like:

```
SELECT 
Name, 
COUNT(distinct Name) AS No. of Calls 
FROM Table
```

Thanks.

Comment: Just use `SELECT Name, COUNT(*) FROM mytable GROUP BY Name`

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Teradata? (Don't tag products not involved.)

Comment: @jarlh edited, thx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to group them and that's all.

```
SELECT
     Name
     COUNT(*) AS [No. of Calls]
FROM
     Table
GROUP BY
     Name
```

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT Name, COUNT(*) AS 'No. of Calls' 
FROM Table
GROUP BY NAME
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```